# Application Insights, convert time difference to milliseconds

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

How can I convert time difference into **milliseconds** in Azure Application Insights

```
let startTime = todatetime('2017-05-15T17:02:23.7148691Z');
let endTime = todatetime('2017-05-15T17:02:25.5430172Z');
let timeDifference = endTime-startTime;
requests
| project timeDifference
| limit 1
```

The above query outputs

```
00:00:01.8281481
```

I would like to display it in milliseconds

For ex: 1828

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide your timespan by another timespan. So, to get number of milliseconds you can do the following:

```
let startTime = todatetime('2017-05-15T17:02:23.7148691Z');
let endTime = todatetime('2017-05-15T17:02:25.5430172Z');
let timeDifference = endTime-startTime;
// get total milliseconds 
requests
| extend timeDifferenceMilliseconds = timeDifference / time(1ms)
| project timeDifferenceMilliseconds
| limit 1
```

More about date and time expressions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-reference#date-and-time-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the built-in `datetime_diff` function and specify milliseconds:

```js
let startTime = todatetime('2017-05-15T17:02:23.7148691Z');
let endTime = todatetime('2017-05-15T17:02:25.5430172Z');
let timeDifference = datetime_diff("Millisecond", endTime, startTime);
requests
| project timeDifference
| limit 1
```

Documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-difffunction